# Displaying size of pictures

Tags: c#, image

I want to display the size of a picture, like the canvas size and then display it in the label. I'm not really sure how to do it, can someone help me please?
This is all I've got:/

```
CanvasSize.Text = PictureBox1.Image.Size;
```

Comment: What is `CanvasSize`? Either way. simply call `PictureBox1.Image.Size.ToString()` will give you something like this: "{Width=322, Height=190}".

For future reference, if you tried to compile that it should tell you something like `Cannot convert type Size to type String` or something. Practically everything will have a `ToString()` method you should be able to call to cast it to a string.

Comment: `CanvasSize.Text = String.Format("Width: {0}px, Height: {0}px", PictureBox1.Image.Width, PictureBox1.Image.Height);`

Comment: @sab669 CanvasSize is a label

Comment: Just to learn from that, could you please explain what the whole line of code does please? @TrevorElliot

Comment: Sorry, it's `CanvasSize.Text = String.Format("Width: {0}px, Height: {1}px", PictureBox1.Image.Width, PictureBox1.Image.Height);`  The [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) method is used to execute a string formatter which allows you to insert values into certain positions.  In this case it would output like, `"Width: 200px, Height: 300px"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CanvasSize.Text = PictureBox1.Image.Size.ToString();
```

If you check the intellisense for the `Size.ToString()` method it says:

> Creates a human-readable string that represents this System.Drawing.Size structure.

The output is of the form:

```
{Width=x, Height=y}
```

If you want to change the way the output is displayed, you can use something like this:

```
CanvasSize.Text = String.Format("{0}px * {1}px",
    PictureBox1.Image.Size.Width, PictureBox1.Image.Height);
```

Comment: Cheers! Is their anyway of displaying it any other way rather than having it displayed as {Width=x, Height=y}

Comment: @AdzT1 Yeah, there is.  I've added an example for you.

Comment: When I put ("{0} x {0}") it'll display as 65 x 65 but when I put it as ("{0 } x {1}") it'll display as 65 x 63 why is this?

Comment: @AdzT1 The numbers in the curly braces represent the arguments that are passed to `String.Format`.  In my example above, `{0}` corresponds to the value of `PictureBox1.Image.Size.Width` and `{1}` corresponds to the value of `PictureBox1.Image.Height`.  In your first example, you're display the width twice.  In your second example, you're display the width and then the height.